# javascript deep json clone

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build small functions to simulate Class related functionalities (ok, I know about frameworks).

In the following example, the code almost work, it fails on deep cloning, somehow the Test.options.* fails to clone/copy, in all created objects options.* is the same reference, any idea what I have been doing wrong?

```
//* class lib *//
function clone(o) {
    var tmp = new o.constructor();
    tmp.__proto__ = o;
    return tmp;
};
var Class = function(o) {
    var tmp = new Function();
    tmp.prototype = clone(o);
    return tmp;
};
//*/

//* object schema *//
var Test = new Class({
    deep: "yes",
    options: {
        inside: true
    }
});
//*/

//* object Test 1 *//
var t1 = new Test();
console.log(t1.deep); // "yes"
t1.deep = "no";
console.log(t1.deep); // "no"
console.log(t1.options.inside); // true
t1.options.inside = false;
console.log(t1.options.inside); // false
//*/

//* object Test 2 *//
var t2 = new Test();
console.log(t2.deep); // "yes"
console.log(t2.options.inside); // should be true but I get false
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

http://overset.org/2007/07/11/javascript-recursive-object-copy-deep-object-copy-pass-by-value/

As noted there, if you're using jQuery, you already have this functionality:

http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.extend

Comment: You can even use the jQuery extend function by just pulling it out of jQuery. It only makes a reference to two, very small other functions in jQuery. Then you could do `obj_new = extend({}, obj_old)` - and the jQuery extend function is sure to be crossbrowser.

Comment: Don't you need to run a deep extend? A deep clone should be the equivalent to running 'new' on the object. A completely new instance with no shared children.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a complete answer but consider that **proto** is only available in mozilla engines (I am assuming you are using Rhino here).

Logically your clone is actually wrong. You are not understanding prototypes here.

A prototype is an object to look up a property in if the parent of the prototype does not contain it (think about it that way). Which means that the following code IS true in your clone structure.

```
var t1 = new Test(); // test object created
var t2 = new Test(); // test object 2 created
t1.options.inside = false;
t2.options.inside; // false
t1.options.inside = true;
t1.options = { inside: false };
t1.options.inside; // false
t2.options.inside; // true
```

This is because options is a shared reference in the prototype. Prototype never clones, it only allows your object to define a property, and thus HIDING the prototype's value.

A true clone will do something like

```
for(var i in o) {
    clone[i] = clone(o[i]); // deep cloning here
    clone[i] = o[i]; // shallow cloning
}
```

This is of course simplified because there are issues with cloning dates, strings, etc. In general cloning is not a simple task.

Check out http://javascript.crockford.com/ it covers lots of object creation mechanisms and describes prototypes well.

Comment: thank you based on your comment I have enhanced clone function to


<code>
    function clone(o) {
     if (o == null || typeof o != "object") { return o; }
     var tmp = new o.constructor();
     for (var key in o) { tmp[key] = clone(o[key]); }
     return tmp;
    };
</code>


it still doesn't work, but I got something interesting with this code, if I do


<code>
    var t1 = clone(new Test());
</code>


instead of


<code>
    var t1 = new Test();
</code>


it will works, but I don't want to wrap my code like that

Comment: In comments you can format code by surrounding it with the back ` (backtick) character. It works in questions/answers too.

Comment: `constructor` is also not standard/cross-browser. And it also doesn't do what you think, and should be avoided at all times.

Comment: @bobince, how is `constructor` not cross-browser? Never had a problem with it. I always use it when calling my parent's constructor. You may be referring to the fact that many home-brewed class systems forget to correctly reset the constructor after chaining the prototype http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html